# can I reload UITableViewController with out reapearing or reloading the table

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am developing an app in which I have to delete the contacts from table ,problem is that when i delete one contact ,I have switch from one view to another then I can see the changing b/c i put the reload method in viewAppear any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should avoid to use `reloadData` to refresh the content of a UITableView, you should only do it if you can't avoid it (ie you replace everything in your table) or the user won't see it (ie in viewWillAppear).

I would suggest to use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert single rows and `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to remove rows.

So you get the indexPath of the row when you delete a contact and call `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:deletedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]`

Those details make the difference between a app and a good app.

Answer (score 1):

you can call `[self.tableView reloadData];` to reload the table view by staying on the current view.

Answer (score 0):

You can immediately reload table after deleting the contact !

Answer (score 0):

Just call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in the `UITableViewController` after the data has been modified. This will update the table view to and reflect the new state of the data.